# Display a simple text label / descrption bubble when user taps on a OverlayItem in MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview

I would like to further annotate the custom markers I have placed on a MapView (using ItemizedOverlay) by displaying a simple text label that appears for a particular item when the onTap event is fired.

This is a trivial exercise in the Google Maps JavaScript API and in MapKit on iPhone, but it is not obvious to me what the best or easiest way to do this is on Android.

Comment: For anybody interested, I have now created my own reusable View and ItemizedOverlay class to achieve this: 
http://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the message to be transient, use a `Toast`. See [here](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Maps/NooYawk/) for an example.

If you want the message to be more persistent, you could:

1. Put the `MapView` inside some container that supports z-axis ordering (e.g., `RelativeLayout`)
2. Add a child of that same container, after the `MapView`, that is your "a simple text label / descrption bubble", with `android:visibility="gone"`
3. When you want to display the bubble, adjust its top and left padding to position it where you want relative to the point, then make it visible
4. When the user does something to make the bubble go away, make its visibility be `GONE` again
5. Repeat steps #3 and #4 as necessary

Comment: this still present an issue if you want maps like baloon which has a little small arrow at the bottom and you need to centralize it, that is if it's TextView i need to know i'm AFTER onMeasure and onLayout where called, and only then can i calculate the (x,y) coords according to the overlay position on the map, this is not so trival.